# Cohen-Macaulayness and regularity of $A/p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265596/cohen-macaulayness-of-r-kx-1-dots-x-n-mathfrak-p) question claimed (and proved) that if $p$ is a prime ideal of $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$
with $\operatorname{ht}(p) \in \{0,1,n-1,n\}$, then $A/p$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Now, let $A$ be a (Noetherian) UFD of Krull dimension $n$ which is Cohen-Macaulay,
and let $p$ be a prime ideal of $A$ with $\operatorname{ht}(p) \in \{0,1,n-1,n \}$.

> **Question 1:** Is it true that $A/p$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

**My answer:** Yes, it is true that $A/p$ is CM, and the same proof holds.

More elaborately:

If $\operatorname{ht}(p)=0$ then $p=(0)$, so trivially $A/p=A/0=A$ is CM.

If $\operatorname{ht}(p)=1$, then $p$ is principal, since a height one prime in a UFD is principal, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Equivalent_conditions_for_a_ring_to_be_a_UFD)(11). Then by the nice proposition in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053646/is-a-quotient-of-ring-of-polynomials-cohen-macaulay) answer, $A/p$ is CM.

If $\operatorname{ht}(p)=n−1$, then $\dim A/p=1$, and one-dimensional integral domains are CM, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring#:%7E:text=power%20series%20ring-,.,example%20any%201%2Ddimensional%20domain.) or [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334558/one-dimensional-integral-domains-are-cohen-macaulay).

If $\operatorname{ht}(p)=n$, then $\dim A/p=0$, hence $A/p$ is a field, and fields are CM.

---

Let us concentrate on $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $p$ a prime ideal of $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$
with $\operatorname{ht}(p)=1$.

Now again $p$ is principal, but $A/p$ is not necessarily regular. Indeed, $(x^2-y^3)$ is a height one prime of $k[x,y]$ and $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)=k[z^2,z^3]$ is CM but not regular (since regular implies normal, but $k[z^2,z^3]$ is not normal, namely, not integrally closed in its field of fractions $k(z)$).

> **Question 2:** What happens if $\operatorname{ht}(p)=n-1$? In that case we have a one-dimensional integral domain $A/p$; is it necessarily regular?.

> **Question 3:** More generally: Could one guarantee regularity of a quotient of $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ by a prime ideal $p$ of height different then $\{0,n\}$? Maybe adding assumptions would help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your counterexample also works for Question 2 since n=2.

Comment: @Francesco, thank you for the comment! You are right, of course.